# try to upgrade gradle and getting error Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This Error Is caused by one of your dependencies in build.gradle(:app)
to solve this issue go to your build.gradle file and review all of your dependencies Probably one of them does not point correctly to its repository, I hope this can help you..